# Multer NodeJS Extension: Unable to upload an Excel File using Multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, xlsx, multer

I tried to use multer to upload files onto my server for my NodeJS/Express web application.

I wrote the following function using multer, however, it just displays a page that says [Object Object] and I have no idea why. I am getting no console logs despite inputing them:

This is my route in my controllers: (I have a form that has a file upload tag on one of my pages)

```
router.post('/upload/file', multer(multConfFile).single('file'), function(req,res){
  if (req.fileValidationError) {
    console.log("This was a valid error");
    return res.send(req.fileValidationError);
  }
  else if (!req.file) {
    console.log("this error occured");
    return res.send('Please select a file to upload');
  }
  else if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
      console.log("Multer error");
      return res.send(err);
  }
  else{
      console.log(req.file)
    res.redirect('back');
  }
```

This is my multer config to allow uploads of Excel files:

```
const multConfFile = {
  storage: multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req,file,callback){
      callback(null, '../models/assets/files');
    },
    filename: function(req, file, callback){
      const ext = file.mimetype.split('/')[1];
      console.log(ext);
      callback(null, file.fieldname + ext);
    }
  }),
  fileFilter: function(req, file, next){
    if(!file){
      next();
    }
    if(!file.originalname.match(/\.(xlsx|xlsb|csv|xlsm)$/)){
      next(null, true);
    }
    else{
      next({message: "File not supported"});
    }
  }
};
```

I am not certain why this is not working? Any suggestions? Could it be a problem with excel file uploads?

Comment: any errors on the console?

Comment: No there were no console errors

Comment: it might have been uploaded successfully but not where you expected it to be, check other directories maybe it's elsewhere